# How to merge a stacked barchart with a point plot in the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, geom-bar

I have this graph.
[image]

And i want to merge it with this one.[image]

This is what I have tried.

```
freq <- read_excel("mg_freq_MFD.xlsx")
med <- read_excel("mg_med_MFD.xlsx")
freq$lookup <- freq$vlookup
freq$lookup <- gsub("|[^|]+$", "", freq$lookup)
freq$esc <- freq$vlookup
freq$esc <- gsub("_[^_]+$", "", freq$esc)
med$lookup <- med$vlookup
med$lookup <- gsub("|[^|]+$", "", med$lookup)
med$esc <- med$vlookup
med$esc <- gsub("_[^_]+$", "", med$esc)
total=20
db<- data.frame(x=1:3,
                y=c(5.5, 6.5,9.7))
escala<-c("4","3","2","1")
tituloQ6<-titulo[titulo$Var=="Q6", "Titulo"]
Q6<-freq[freq$esc=="Entrevista_final|1|ii|1|esc_Q6",c("var","mod","PERCENT")]
Q6med<-med[med$esc=="Entrevista_final|1|ii|1|Q6",c("var","mean")]

ggplot(Q6, aes(x=var, y=PERCENT,fill = factor(x=mod, levels = escala)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", width =.5, color="red3")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("4"="white","3"="#fe5f5f","2"="red","1"="red3"))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  geom_text(aes(label=sprintf(PERCENT,fmt="%1.0f")),
            position = position_stack(vjust=0.5))+
  theme_classic()+
  ggtitle(tituloQ6)+
  labs(x="",
       y=NULL,
       caption = (paste("n= ", total)))+
  guides(y="none")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  geom_point(data=Q6med, x=var, y=mean)
```

But i get an error on the factor.

```
Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `factor()`:
! object 'mod' not found
Backtrace:
  1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
 17. base::factor(x = mod, levels = escala)
Error in geom_point(data = Q6med, x = var, y = mean) :
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `factor()`:
! object 'mod' not found
```

```r
structure(list(vlookup = c("Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C1|1", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C1|2", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C3|1", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C3|4", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C3|2", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C3|3", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|2018", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|2020", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|1993", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|2015", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|2016", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|1996", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|99", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|2017", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|2004", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|2019", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|2002", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|2021", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_2|99", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_2|2018"), cruza1 = c("Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final"), 
    mod1 = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), cruza2 = c("Q3_nova", 
    "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", 
    "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", 
    "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", 
    "Q3_nova"), mod2 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
    ), var = c("C1", "C1", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C4_1", "C4_1", 
    "C4_1", "C4_1", "C4_1", "C4_1", "C4_1", "C4_1", "C4_1", "C4_1", 
    "C4_1", "C4_1", "C4_2", "C4_2"), mod = c("1", "2", "1", "4", 
    "2", "3", "2018", "2020", "1993", "2015", "2016", "1996", 
    "99", "2017", "2004", "2019", "2002", "2021", "99", "2018"
    ), pop_extrapolada = c(22, 17, 32, 3, 3, 1, 4, 10, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 10, 2, 3), PERCENT = c(56.4102564102564, 
    43.5897435897436, 82.051282051282, 7.69230769230769, 7.69230769230769, 
    2.56410256410256, 10.2564102564103, 25.6410256410256, 2.56410256410256, 
    2.56410256410256, 5.12820512820513, 2.56410256410256, 5.12820512820513, 
    5.12820512820513, 2.56410256410256, 10.2564102564103, 2.56410256410256, 
    25.6410256410256, 15.3846153846154, 23.0769230769231), count = c(22, 
    17, 32, 3, 3, 1, 4, 10, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 10, 2, 
    3), BA = c(39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
    39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 13, 13), StdErr = c(0.0795074974876938, 
    0.0795074974876938, 0.0615313285518115, 0.0427252055542318, 
    0.0427252055542318, 0.0253433535020364, 0.0486447864199686, 
    0.0700118062133025, 0.0253433535020364, 0.0253433535020364, 
    0.0353661791821834, 0.0253433535020364, 0.0353661791821834, 
    0.0353661791821834, 0.0253433535020364, 0.0486447864199686, 
    0.0253433535020364, 0.0700118062133025, 0.100484337629983, 
    0.117340426124568), LowerCLMean = c(0.407774134748444, 0.279569006543315, 
    0.699529312635895, 0, 0, 0, 0.00691824151210088, 0.118752349327158, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00691824151210088, 0, 0.118752349327158, 
    0, 0), UpperCLMean = c(0.720430993456685, 0.592225865251556, 
    0.941496328389746, 0.160929799423163, 0.160929799423163, 
    0.0754713784093646, 0.198209963616104, 0.394068163493355, 
    0.0754713784093646, 0.0754713784093646, 0.120819383213079, 
    0.0754713784093646, 0.120819383213079, 0.120819383213079, 
    0.0754713784093646, 0.198209963616104, 0.0754713784093646, 
    0.394068163493355, 0.352798149154327, 0.463095108198593), 
    ME = c(15.6328429354121, 15.6328429354121, 12.0983507876925, 
    8.40067225000863, 8.40067225000863, 4.9830352768339, 9.56458610520017, 
    13.7657907083098, 4.9830352768339, 4.9830352768339, 6.95373319310279, 
    4.9830352768339, 6.95373319310279, 6.95373319310279, 4.9830352768339, 
    9.56458610520017, 4.9830352768339, 13.7657907083098, NA, 
    NA), StdDev = c(4.55932029745697, 4.03560271072923, 5.42183783041485, 
    1.72749876078217, 1.72749876078217, 1, 1.99211042289525, 
    3.1247047104581, 1, 1, 1.41235641966466, 1, 1.41235641966466, 
    1.41235641966466, 1, 1.99211042289525, 1, 3.1247047104581, 
    1.40830867828517, 1.71755640373177), lookup = c("Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C1|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C1|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C3|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C3|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C3|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C3|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_1|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_2|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4_2|"), esc = c("Entrevista_final|1|Q3", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|C4")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```r
structure(list(vlookup = c("Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q6_1", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q6_2", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q6_3", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9_1", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9_2", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9_3", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9_4", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9_5", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9_6", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9_7", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9_8", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q6_1", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q6_2", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q6_3", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9_1", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9_2", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9_3", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9_4", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9_5", 
"Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9_6"), cruza1 = c("Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", 
"Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final", "Entrevista_final"), 
    mod1 = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), cruza2 = c("Q3_nova", 
    "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", 
    "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", 
    "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", "Q3_nova", 
    "Q3_nova"), mod2 = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
    ".", ".", ".", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"
    ), var = c("Q6_1", "Q6_2", "Q6_3", "Q9_1", "Q9_2", "Q9_3", 
    "Q9_4", "Q9_5", "Q9_6", "Q9_7", "Q9_8", "Q6_1", "Q6_2", "Q6_3", 
    "Q9_1", "Q9_2", "Q9_3", "Q9_4", "Q9_5", "Q9_6"), mean = c(5.69767441860465, 
    7.18604651162791, 6.81395348837209, 6.325, 6.65, 7.68292682926829, 
    8.41463414634146, 8.07142857142857, 8.14634146341463, 8.59523809523809, 
    8.54761904761905, 6.61538461538461, 6.94871794871795, 6.43589743589744, 
    6.72222222222222, 6.75675675675676, 8.44736842105263, 8.23684210526316, 
    8.44736842105263, 8.57894736842105), ba = c(43, 43, 43, 40, 
    40, 41, 41, 42, 41, 42, 42, 39, 39, 39, 36, 37, 38, 38, 38, 
    38), N = c(43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 39, 
    39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39), StdErr = c(0.470914185560204, 
    0.410281576101709, 0.416835766228631, 0.521900205807444, 
    0.402892230805839, 0.391375466555417, 0.269664126081159, 
    0.268409952413896, 0.304135230479118, 0.316349111010602, 
    0.250470946520814, 0.400365075596811, 0.407435440466744, 
    0.349722774823449, 0.426532227843502, 0.307106063412623, 
    0.290287995830448, 0.289658029819206, 0.240601576847107, 
    0.257153023503742), LowerCLMean = c(4.77203852970105, 6.37957987882874, 
    5.9946205378507, 5.29900543427478, 5.85799052940539, 6.91360135641181, 
    7.88453734944423, 7.54379718753762, 7.54850383690226, 7.97340904610116, 
    8.0552828750472, 5.82842110058807, 6.14784579920957, 5.7484818728014, 
    5.88370991085601, 6.1530446667685, 7.87675025833957, 7.66744195540224, 
    7.97440181971579, 8.07346251229383), UpperCLMean = c(6.62331030750825, 
    7.99251314442708, 7.63328643889348, 7.35099456572522, 7.4420094705946, 
    8.45225230212478, 8.94473094323869, 8.59905995531952, 8.74417908992701, 
    9.21706714437503, 9.0399552201909, 7.40234813018116, 7.74959009822633, 
    7.12331299899347, 7.56073453358844, 7.36046884674501, 9.0179865837657, 
    8.80624225512407, 8.92033502238947, 9.08443222454828), media_sem_fe = c(5.69767441860465, 
    7.18604651162791, 6.81395348837209, 6.325, 6.65, 7.68292682926829, 
    8.41463414634146, 8.07142857142857, 8.14634146341463, 8.59523809523809, 
    8.54761904761905, 6.61538461538461, 6.94871794871795, 6.43589743589744, 
    6.72222222222222, 6.75675675675676, 8.44736842105263, 8.23684210526316, 
    8.44736842105263, 8.57894736842105), ME = c(0.925635888903602, 
    0.806466632799168, 0.819332950521389, 1.02599456572522, 0.792009470594609, 
    0.769325472856485, 0.530096796897231, 0.527631383890947, 
    0.597837626512375, 0.62182904913694, 0.49233617257185, 0.786963514796548, 
    0.800872149508378, 0.687415563096039, 0.838512311366217, 
    0.60371208998826, 0.570618162713064, 0.569400149860914, 0.47296660133684, 
    0.505484856127225), lookup = c("Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|"), esc = c("Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q6", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q6", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q6", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|.|Q9", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q6", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q6", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q6", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9", "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9", 
    "Entrevista_final|1|Q3_nova|0|Q9")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: We cant reproduce this error without your dataset. Could you paste it in to the question or use a fuller set of simulated data?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) which means to include a snippet of all data necessary to run your code. Also, it would be helpful to describe clearly what's the issue and include any error messages you get. As is I can only say that `geom_point(data=Q6med, x=var, y=mean)` looks weird and should probably be `geom_point(data=Q6med, aes(x=var, y=mean))`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My dataset is save as a excel file, how can I put it here so someone can help?

Comment: @GonGas, please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 for examples on how to use `dput` to post a sample of your data. Depending on the variability of your data, I suggest something like `dput(head(freq, 20))` (and same for `med`), ensuring that there are enough of each of your factors to be able to plot something. If there are many columns, only include columns being used here. Feel free to use something other than `head`, for example hand-picking rows to ensure we have the variability needed to best demo a plot.

Comment: @r2evans i've done the dput not sure if it is right

Comment: Can I get any help? I really can get this to work